# Displaying a loading gif every time when a date picker date is changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a laravel application which shows some stats to my users.

On my front end blade, I'm displaying few widgets where each widget contain's a specific stat.

Following widget is to show number of total orders.

```
<div class="row mt-3" id="shopify_row1">
        <div class="col-md-2" id="shopify_widget1">
            <div class="jumbotron bg-dark text-white">
                <img class="img-fluid pull-left" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2092/100/social-35-512.png" width="32" height="32">
                <h6 class="text-secondary mt-2 px-4">Shopify</h6>
                <hr class="border border-white">
                <h5 class="text-white">Total Orders</h5>
                <span class="tot_o" id="tot_o">{{ $tot_o }}</span> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Like this widget, I have 5 more widgets to display 5 different stats.

In every widget initially I'm displaying stats for the current date, eg: if the total number of orders for the day is 0, it shows 0...

Then, I have added a a date picker as I can get the data only for a particular day.

```
<td>
      <input id="date" class="date form-control" type="date">
</td>
```

And following is my jQuery...

```
<script>
        $(document).on('change', '#date', function (e) {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : '/shopify_data',
            data : {selected_date : $('#date').val()},
            success:function(data){

            $('#tot_o').empty(); 
            $('#tot_sum').empty(); 
            $('#avg_ov').empty(); 
            $('#cus').empty();
            $('#item_sum').empty();
            $('#orders').empty();
            var total_orders = data.tot_o;
            var total_sales = data.sum;
            var currency = data.crr;
            var avg_ov = data.avg_ov;
            var cus = data.cus;
            var item_sum = data.item_sum;
            var orders = data.orders;
            $('#tot_o').append(total_orders);
            $('#tot_sum').append(total_sales);
            $('#avg_ov').append(avg_ov);
            $('#cus').append(cus);
            $('#item_sum').append(item_sum);
            $('#orders').append(orders);
            //console.log(total_orders);

            },
            timeout:10000
        });

    });    
    </script>
```

This entire code works perfectly, but now I need to add a loading gif till the updated results get displayed on the date change.

What changes should I do to above jQuery in order to add the loading gif...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways how you can create the loading gif. One would be to create an element in your blade template that is hidden or shown by using a class.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="loader hidden"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');

$(document).on('change', '#date', function (e) {
    loader.classList.remove('hidden');
    // your other code..
}
```

And inside your `success` function you add the `hidden` class which should hide the loading element again.

```
success: function(data){
    loader.classList.add('hidden');
    // your existing code..
},
```

However, I would instead add a `complete` block, which ensures that on failure as on success the loading element is hidden.

```
$.ajax({
    // your existing code..
    complete: () => {
        loader.classList.add('hidden');
    }
}
```

Comment: this work using `display: none;` via css is quick solution and changing it back to visible via javascript ... downside is if user decided to disable javascript on browser the page would look weird

Comment: If a user decided to disable JS all the web will look weird for him these days. OP got AJAX operations there. So with JS disabled nothing will work anyways.

Comment: "nothing will work" may be a bit exaggerated as there are special cases like Google, but for most websites that indeed is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can place loading gif in any place of DOM with `style="display: none"`.
Next, in your script before ajax you can show gif and after success or fail result hide it again:

```
<script>
    let gif = $('.loading-gif'); // Your loading gif

    $(document).on('change', '#date', function (e) {
        
        gif.show(); // Show loading gif

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : '/shopify_data',
            data : {selected_date : $('#date').val()},
            success:function(data){
            gif.hide(); // Hide gif

            $('#tot_o').empty(); 
            $('#tot_sum').empty(); 
            $('#avg_ov').empty(); 
            $('#cus').empty();
            $('#item_sum').empty();
            $('#orders').empty();
            var total_orders = data.tot_o;
            var total_sales = data.sum;
            var currency = data.crr;
            var avg_ov = data.avg_ov;
            var cus = data.cus;
            var item_sum = data.item_sum;
            var orders = data.orders;
            $('#tot_o').append(total_orders);
            $('#tot_sum').append(total_sales);
            $('#avg_ov').append(avg_ov);
            $('#cus').append(cus);
            $('#item_sum').append(item_sum);
            $('#orders').append(orders);
            //console.log(total_orders);

            },
            timeout:10000
        });
    });    
</script>
```